# Change Email Template On Specific Order Status:Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, sales-order, email-templates, order-email

I am trying to use different e-mail template for one of my custom order status when the status is changed from the admin.

I have used the event **sales_order_save_after**

```
<observer name="sales_order_save_after" instance="Hawk\OrderFlow\Observer\Sales\Order\SalesOrderAfterSave"/>
```

And created an observer like follows:

```
<?php

namespace Hawk\OrderFlow\Observer\Sales\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderAfterSave implements ObserverInterface {

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
 */
protected $_request;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
 */
protected $_transportBuilder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * For logger, var/log
 */
protected $_logger;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)

{

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $lastOrderId = $order->getId();
    $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();

    try {

        if($orderStatus  == "viewed_by_admin") {
            $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $template = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('13') //Where 13 is the Email Template ID created in the admin pannel under the Stores -> Email Templates
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store]);
            return $template;
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
}    
}
```

Still not using my defined email template rather then still using the default email template from admin configuration, Is there anything I am missing here please guide about it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is good and you followed good approach as per M2 standards. It needs some improvement to make it compatible and error-free in a maximum of cases

1. Exception Handling.
   `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); if( !empty($order) ){ // do code here }`
2. Naming convention. Do use camel-case for variables. `$order_status` should be `$orderStatus`.
3. It is observer so you won't be able to track if that happened or not so do wrap it in try-catch and log accordingly ( do add a check if logs are enabled or not ).

Comment: Thanks for the improvements you have mentioned, i have posted the least code here, Sure i will take and i am taking care of these standards, Can you please check the updated question now and try to answer that, will be appreciated.